# Error:No space left on device in Kaggle Notebook

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I am trying to cross-validate my model using scikit-learn's cross_val_score.
I tried using multiple cores by setting n_jobs=-1 but it resulted in

**OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device**

Code given below results in  error:

```
cross_val_score(mod1, train_feats1, target, cv=5, scoring=make_scorer(accuracy_score), n_jobs=-1)
```

whereas:

```
cross_val_score(mod1, train_feats1, target, cv=5, scoring=make_scorer(accuracy_score), n_jobs=1)
```

works perfectly fine.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

As far I can read Kaggle allows up to 4 CPUs for parallel computations.
Here's the link: https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/39790

How can I parallelize my cross-validation process, using all four CPUs?

Answer (score 3):

I overcame this problem by setting JOBLIB_TEMP_FOLDER variable using following code in Python notebook.

```
%env JOBLIB_TEMP_FOLDER=/tmp
```

Hope that helps!